# Is the following ideal prime or the following quotient ring flat?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, flatness

Consider the ideal $$I := (xy - 4, z^2 - zy - y) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z].$$ I'd would like to know if it is prime.

If it is prime, then I believe I can conclude that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/I$ is a flat module over $\mathbb{Z}$. If it is not prime, then can we show that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/I$ is flat (or not flat) over $\mathbb{Z}$ using a different method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed $I$ is prime. We have a ring injection $$\begin{align} \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/I & = \mathbb{Z}[x,4/x,z]/(z^2-(4/x)z-(4/x)) \\ & \hookrightarrow\mathbb{Z}[x,1/x,z]/(xz^2-4z-4). \end{align}$$

The latter morphism is the same as $$\mathbb{Z}[x,4/x]\oplus \mathbb{Z}[x,4/x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x,1/x]\oplus \mathbb{Z}[x,1/x]$$  and in fact injective.

$xz^2-4z-4$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x,z]$. For, if not, it factorizes as $(xz+P(x))(z+Q(x))$ where $P(x)+xQ(x)=-4, P(x)Q(x)=-4.$ From the second equality we obtain $P(x),Q(x)\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$, contradicting the first one. Thus $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/I$ is an integral domain.

Since $\mathbb{Z}\cap (xz^2-4z-4)=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x,z]$, $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/I$ is an injection and in particular $ \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/I$ is a torsion-free module over $\mathbb{Z}$. This is a characterization of flatness for modules over a PID.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but $A=\mathbb Z[x]/(2x)$ is not flat over $\mathbb Z$ (because of 2-torsion), yet $(2x)\cap {\mathbb Z}=0$, and $\mathbb Z$ injects into $A$.

Comment: @peterag I appreciate your comments. You are right but in this case I first showed $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/I$ is an integral domain and $\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ are nonzerodivisors on it.

Comment: Acknowledged! I'll leave my comment since it leads to yours.

Comment: @Acrobatic Thank you for this answer. Essentially, we can observe that $y$ is nonzero and hence we work over the localization at $y \ne 0$. Now the generators become a monic polynomial in $x$ and a monic quadratic in $v$, (the latter being irreducible) which makes our ideal prime. Is this the correct reasoning?

Comment: @KSAKY Your argument might be OK but could you be more explicit about why we can work over the localization at $y$? There are cases that $\mathfrak{a}\subset A$ is not prime but $\mathfrak{a}A_S$ is prime (for instance, $A=\mathbb{R}[x,y], \mathfrak{a}=(xy), S=\{1, y, y^2,\dots \}.$)

Comment: @Acrobatic By substituting $\frac{4}{x}$ as $y$, aren't you localizing at $x$?

Comment: @KSAKY What I used is the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(xy-4) \simeq \mathbb{Z}[x,4/x].$  Localization at $x$ has nothing to do with this; $x$ is not invertible in the right hand side.

Comment: @Acrobatic I see. Yes, this isomorphism is something slightly different as $1/4$ is not an element on the RHS (no invertible elements were introduced). If it was $(xy - 1)$ then it becomes the localization at $x$.